# Intel Wireless-N 7260 slow on linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, drivers, intel-core-i7

I just bought a new Acer Aspire V7-582PG which has an Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-N 7260 (rev 73) Wifi card.

In windows, everything works fine, but using linux, the internet speed is quite slow (Linux: 100kb/s - 500kB/s vs windows: 1-2MB/s). I tried Fedora 20 and Ubuntu 14.04-beta now, both are having the same problem (both are running Kernel 3.13.0). I also tried two different WiFi networks, same issues on both.

If I use ethernet on linux, it also achieves 1-2MB/s, so it's not the application layer.

lspci tells me that the kernel driver in use is iwlwifi, this should be the correct driver AFAIK:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wirelesss 7260 (rev 73)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-N 7260
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 67
Memory at b3500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number [...]
Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [154] Vendor Specific Information: ID=cafe Rev=1 Len=014 <?>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I don't see any errors in dmesg or syslog, nevertheless here some logs (taken over the time of enabling wifi, connecting to the access point, downloading a large file)

*dmesg:*

```
[ 1668.921529] wlan0: authenticate with [mac]
[ 1668.923754] wlan0: send auth to [mac] (try 1/3)
[ 1668.925720] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1668.928533] wlan0: associate with [mac] (try 1/3)
[ 1668.931371] wlan0: RX AssocResp from [mac] (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1668.931901] wlan0: associated
[ 1668.931922] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 1767.843948] systemd-hostnamed[4116]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

*syslog:*

```
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> enable requested (sleeping: no  enabled: no)
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> waking up and re-enabling...
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): bringing up device.
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (eth0): bringing up device.
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (eth0): preparing device.
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu kernel: [ 1638.766440] r8169 0000:05:00.1 eth0: link down
Apr 15 15:06:26 ubuntu kernel: [ 1638.766502] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): bringing up device.
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> WiFi now enabled by radio killswitch
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): bringing up device.
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1642.036186] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1642.037447] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1642.037669] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1642.049872] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0) supports 5 scan SSIDs
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> disconnected
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0) supports 5 scan SSIDs
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2060]: wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Apr 15 15:06:29 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2060]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Apr 15 15:06:33 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Ikarus'.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'Ikarus'
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): preparing device.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'Ikarus' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Ikarus' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'Ikarus'
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Apr 15 15:06:53 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2060]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2060]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with [mac] (SSID='Ikarus' freq=2412 MHz)
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu kernel: [ 1668.921529] wlan0: authenticate with [mac]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu kernel: [ 1668.923754] wlan0: send auth to [mac] (try 1/3)
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2060]: wlan0: Trying to associate with [mac] (SSID='Ikarus' freq=2412 MHz)
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu kernel: [ 1668.925720] wlan0: authenticated
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu kernel: [ 1668.928533] wlan0: associate with [mac] (try 1/3)
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2060]: wlan0: Associated with [mac]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu kernel: [ 1668.931371] wlan0: RX AssocResp from [mac] (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu kernel: [ 1668.931901] wlan0: associated
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu kernel: [ 1668.931922] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2060]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with [mac] [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2060]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to [mac] completed [id=0 id_str=]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Ikarus'.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> dhclient started with pid 3971
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu dhclient: All rights reserved.
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu dhclient: 
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/[mac]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/[mac]
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Apr 15 15:06:56 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.20.139 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x77e564c9)
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.20.139 from 192.168.20.1
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu dhclient: bound to 192.168.20.139 -- renewal in 1394 seconds.
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info>   address 192.168.20.139
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info>   gateway 192.168.20.1
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info>   hostname 'ubuntu'
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.30.1'
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.20.1'
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info>   domain name 'localwlan'
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Apr 15 15:06:57 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Policy set 'Ikarus' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu dnsmasq[3233]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu dnsmasq[3233]: using nameserver 192.168.20.1#53
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu dnsmasq[3233]: using nameserver 192.168.30.1#53
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu dbus[1169]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Apr 15 15:06:58 ubuntu dbus[1169]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 15 15:07:05 ubuntu ntpdate[4049]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset 0.000059 sec
Apr 15 15:07:17 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 15 15:07:17 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 15 15:07:17 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 15 15:07:17 ubuntu NetworkManager[1729]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Apr 15 15:07:26 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2060]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
```

*ifconfig:*

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [mac]
      inet addr:192.168.20.139  Bcast:192.168.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e8b:fdff:fe78:a807/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:267157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:139061 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:400828359 (400.8 MB)  TX bytes:12138586 (12.1 MB)
```

*iwconfig:*

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"Ikarus"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: [mac]
      Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:952   Missed beacon:0
```

Is this a known driver bug? Or is it a hardware failure and I should send the notebook back? I'm wondering why it works on windows though.

**edit:**
Looking into /lib/firmware, I see two firmware versions installed.

```
$ ls -l |grep iwlwifi-7260
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  683236 17. Mär 19:38 iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  679780 17. Mär 19:38 iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
```

However, modinfo says it's using iwlwifi-7260-7. Is that a problem? Can I tell it to use the newer iwlwifi-7260-8? Or is the number in the end not about updates but about different card versions?

Here the output of modinfo:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.9-200.fc20.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:d
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     D6BB6B39D0A7CAE63C6FE2E
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005490bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005290bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005590bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005190bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005090bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000502Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009410bc*sc*i*
[...]
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.9-200.fc20.x86_64 SMP mod_unload 
signer:         Fedora kernel signing key
sig_key:        C3:7D:D7:50:43:06:5A:DE:BE:24:34:7F:CD:03:35:FA:C5:D0:3D:63
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
parm:           debug:debug output mask (uint)
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
```

Comment: Intel is natorious known for releasing horrible drivers for their wireless adapters. What driver release are you using?  We also need to know what 802.11 the device is using and what modes the access point supports.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the iwlwifi drivers shipped with linux kernel 3.13.0. The access point supports 54Mbit, no 802.11n (I think this means 802.11abg)

Answer (score 4):

I found that switching off Bluetooth helped.

It is on the same chip, but using a Bluetooth mouse and wlan makes the wlan crash every minute. Without Bluetooth it worked for a while longer.

Still I get a few "deauthenticated" and "rekeying" messages and sometimes it recovers, sometimes I have to turn the wifi off/on in the system settings.

Strange behaviour.

I have found many tips (disable watchdog, the "n" part of 8011, etc.) but none worked for me.
And I haven't found any connection to Bluetooth usage....

Answer (score 1):

I have a Thinkpad X240 running Ubuntu 14.10 which has been suffering from slow 7260 connection speeds (20MBps vs 80-90MBps for other non-7260 laptops) on my home and other wifi networks.

Trying numerous tips and tweaks gleaned online has had no effect, but running the latest 3.19 mainline kernel and 7260-10 firmware has, for the first time, upped the speed to the standard 80-90.